# Ignore first column in datatables CSV export

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to export a CSV file based on data from jQuery datatables and I would like it to exclude the first column of data, here is my current script.

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    lengthMenu: [
        [ 10, 25, 50, -1 ],
        [ '10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', 'Show all' ]
    ],
     buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'pageLength'
    ]
} );
} );
</script>
```

What do I need to add to get that to work, please

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the `exportOptions` within your `buttons` definition.

```
buttons: [
       {
           extend: 'pdf',           
           exportOptions: {
                columns: [1,2,3,4] // indexes of the columns that should be printed,
            }                      // Exclude indexes that you don't want to print.
       },
       {
           extend: 'csv',
           exportOptions: {
                columns: [1,2,3,4] 
            }

       },
       {
           extend: 'excel',
           exportOptions: {
                columns: [1,2,3,4] 
            }
       }         
    ]
```

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is good, but if you're not sure about the number of columns that you need to export, another approach will work:

```
buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'excel', 
        exportOptions: {
            columns: ':gt(0)' 
        }
    }
]
```

The first column is specified by offset 0, so this code says to export any columns that are greater than 0 (i.e., every other column except the first one).

Comment: I find this is a much better answer and I think it should be the accepted answer, since there is no need to explicitly state the column indexes besides the first. Say you have a DataTable with 30 columns. Instead of `columns: [ 1, 2, 3, ... 30]`, you could just use this quick one-liner. In addition, the table structure may update over time and columns may be added or removed, so this code would be independent of those changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example provided in the **Official** dataTables forums:

```
exportOptions: {
                 columns: function (idx, data, node) {
                     if (idx == 0) {
                         return false;
                     }
                     return true;
                  },
              },
```

Using this function, you can exclude multiple columns using index, data or the node value and you don't need to know the number of index, you can use same for the rows as well, just replace the ***columns*** with ***rows*** inside the function.

**Link To Forum:** [Function to exclude columns From DataTable Jquery](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/60354/function-to-exclude-columns-from-print)

The link may not work based on what year you are accessing it!